# story generation with strong restrictions

Tags: chat-bots, story-generation

I try to write a story with only a large subset of a given language, for instance, all French words not containing the letter 'a'.

The tools I tried mostly understood the request, writing a story with MOST words not containing "a", but still leaving a strong proportion of "bad words" (such as the word "bad" :).

From my understanding of story generation algorithms, it does not seem too difficult to modifiy the core algorithm to just assign probability 0 to words not containing the letter 'a', but I don't know these tools well enough to see if one of them gives this possibility to the user.

Would you know such a tool able to follow perfectly such a strong restriction? I emphasize that I am not interested in writing a story without the letter "a", this is just an example, I just want to be able to feed a (very large) set of words, say a few thousands, and the algorithm should write a story with just those words.

Thanks in advance